# How to respond to negative questions (adjectives)?

Tags: adjectives, questions, negation

My friend got me this question:

When somebody asks, **"Is it not available?"**

Should I say:
(1) "Yes, it is not available." OR
(2) "No, it is not available."?

I know it would be better to use the word *unavailable*. I checked out another question titled "*How to answer a negative question without ambiguity?*" But it isn't about adjectives so I'm starting a new question. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

This (what your friend said, not your post) is a fundamentally confusing style of question:  any choice of "yes" or "no" will potentially cause confusion, although in this case most people would say "No, it's not available" if it isn't in fact available, and if it is available would be a bit confused about how to answer.

If anyone ever asks me a question like this I always avoid saying "yes" or "no" and simply state the case, like "It's available", or "It's not available".  I'd advise you to do the same.

Comment: Thank you for your kind answer. My friend and I are from Hong Kong and it's not that common to use English to ask for such kind of information. But after all, the negation in questions does not affect the yes/no in the answer!

Comment: Yeah, in a way "Is it not available?" is equivalent to asking "Is it available?", which doesn't make sense, logically, and is part of the reason why it's such a confusing style of question.